# How to get testcase information from robot framework

Tags: python, robotframework

Is there a way I can get test case information from the test cases file
into the actual functions (I'm using python)?

Example:

I have this test case in my test cases file:

```
Check Health
[Documentation]    |     health check
[Tags]             |     health
Check System Health
```

My python code has a function:

```
check_system_health
```

that does something.

How can I get the test case headline, documentation, tags 
in my check_system_health function?

Answer (score 4):

Robot provides several [automatic variables](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#automatic-variables) which are defined in the user guide. Among these are `${TEST NAME}`, `${TEST DOCUMENTATION}` and `@{TEST TAGS}`. You can pass these in as arguments, or you can access them directly from python by [getting a reference to the built-in library](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#using-builtin-library) and calling the `Get Variable Value` keyword.